# Are Outlook (MS Office) and OWA email filter rules different?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, outlook-web-access

Both Outlook (the native Application) as OWA (outlook web access) are email clients used for MS Exchange Email server. Both support filtering emails.

I wonder if there is any difference, and if so what is the difference in which both applications employ/use/provide email filter rules (e.g. a rule to treat all emails arriving in inbox with a certain criterium (e.g. `Subject` email header contained certain words) in a specific way (e.g. to move it into a specific dedicated folder) )

The core difference I suspect - albeit being unable to verify on my own yet - is that the OWA filters are carried out on the server-side and are applied always, while the native application MS Office Outlook email filters are relevant only "locally".

From https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Inbox-rules-in-Outlook-Web-App-EDEA3D17-00C9-434B-B9B7-26EE8D9F5622

> Each rule you create will take up space in a **hidden section** of your
>   mailbox. This section is limited to 64 KB. The actual amount of space
>   a rule uses depends on several factors, such as how long the name is
>   and how many conditions you've applied. When you reach the 64 KB
>   limit, you'll be warned that you can't create any more rules. If that
>   happens, you'll have to delete or simplify some of your existing rules
>   before you can create more. Some ways you can reduce the space used by
>   rules are:

Is this quote an indication about the difference between the rules in OWA and Outlook Client ? At least outlook client did not tell any limits (such as the 64KB for OWA)